# Angular not working in eclipse IDE for node express project

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I am trying to move my angular controller code into a separate file and the JS file is throwing errors like angular not recognised. It was working when the controller was in the same file

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
    <title>title </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js'>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js'>
<script src="public/js/ang.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="democontroller">
    <h1>title </h1>
    <p>Welcome to title </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ang.js file**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.controller("democontroller", function($scope,$http,$window) {

    alert("hi");
});
```

node's app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("ready on port 8000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Check the network panel and console in chrome see if any requests are missed or if it loads your external JS file, also should probably update the angular version to 1.4.x 1.0.8 is a couple of years old at this point it's the version I started with.

Comment: Do you see ang.js get loaded in the network panel, you should be able to search in there and find it and see the response.

Comment: No, its not getting loaded...but the src path is correct. I created a js folder in the publics folder and placed the file there. Thing is the js file itself is showing errors. it says angular not defined, alert not defined.

Comment: Angular not defined means the angular.js file itself isn't getting loaded, double check the path, try to load the JS file in the browser with the path you expect it to be at, if the file doesn't load that way then it's not going to with a script.

Comment: ang.js you mean? its opening in the browser with the path. Do I have to add anything else in the ang.js or app.js?

Comment: No was referring to " it says angular not defined" everything looks fine regarding the file contents, but you should see that the index.html response in the network panel contains the script tag referencing the ang.js file and you should see that in the network panel, use the disable cache checkbox in the panel to be sure you aren't getting cached resources.

Comment: okay yeah I get it...so how do I check for angular js file in eclipse IDE? I just created a node express project and started working with it. I am a complete beginner. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just check out everything that's going on from the chrome network debug panel, what's going on in the IDE should be irrelevant at least for the time being.  Would also suggest you grab an IRC client and /join #angularjs, there's usually a couple of us around and it's a better way to get more real time responses, we can bring the answer back here afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out in the chat I believe the code was missing closing `</script>` tags.